# reading user/group mappings from a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to add new groups and add users to the groups in SharePoint using PowerShell. So far I have this script which does the task. I want to modify the script so it can read from a text file which has the groups and the users in this format (or recommend another way of doing it).

```
Group1

User1,User2,User3 etc.


Group2

User5,User7 etc.
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this task?

```psh
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$SiteUrl = "http://www.dev.com"
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteUrl

$description = "Group with contribute access."
$permissionLevel = "Contribute"

$groups = "1", "2"

foreach($groupName in $groups)
{
    $web.SiteGroups.Add($groupName, $web.SiteUsers["Test\data"], $web.SiteUsers["Test\data"], $description)  
    $group = $web.SiteGroups[$groupName]  
    $loc = Get-Location     
    $Users = "Test\data"    
    $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)  
    $roleDefinition = $web.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions[$permissionLevel]  
    $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition)  
    $web.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)  
    $web.Update() 
    foreach ($User in $Users) { 
        $Web.EnsureUser($User)  
        Set-SPUser -Identity $User -Web $SiteUrl -Group $group  
    } 

}

$Web.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a large input file I'd split the file multiple ways:

1. at 3 consecutive line breaks to separate the groups from each other,
2. at 2 consecutive line breaks to separate the user list from the group name,
3. at commas to get the list of user names.

Something like this should do:

```psh
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\test.txt' -Raw) -split "`r`n`r`n`r`n" | ? { $_ } | % {
  $group, $userlist = $_ -split "`r`n`r`n"
  $users = $userlist -split ','

  # do stuff with $group and $users
}
```

Note that the parameter `-Raw` requires PowerShell v3 or newer. With older versions use `-join` before `-split`:

```psh
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\test.txt') -join "`r`n" -split "`r`n`r`n`r`n" | ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ansgar but this is not working correctly. I ll update my question with the new format I have like u suggested but it's not working correctly.  The $group name is showing all User values and $User is empty

Comment: @sp9 If you have 3 line breaks between groups and 2 line breaks between group and userlist you need to adjust the splitting patterns accordingly, of course. See updated answer. BTW, this would be a lot simpler if you chose an easier to handle format, for instance `group1:user1,user2,user3...`